# Write/Read struct to/from file in C

Tags: c, struct

I am very confused how to write/read data with file and struct. I have searched in the internet but still confused.

when I want to save the struct, it will save in Chinese language. and when I want to read from the file, it will read something else.

can you help me?

this is my struct

```
struct yogurt
{
    char name[50];
    char topping[50];
    int size;
    int harga;
}*record;
```

And this is the part of the code that handle write/read to the file

```
void menu1(void)
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("data.txt","a");
    int nm,tp,sz;
    record = (struct yogurt *)malloc(sizeof(struct yogurt));
    bool loop;
    char sure[10];
    while (loop = true)
    {
        printf("Input your yogurt [chocolate/vanilla/strawberry] : ");
        scanf("%s",record->name);
        if (strcmp(record->name,"chocolate") == 0)
        {
            nm = 9;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(record->name,"vanilla") == 0)
        {
            nm = 7;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(record->name,"strawberry") == 0)
        {
            nm = 10;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (loop = true)
    {
        printf("Input your topping [kitkat/jelly/kiwi/mango] : ");
        scanf("%s",record->topping);
        if (strcmp(record->topping,"kitkat") == 0)
        {
            tp = 6;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(record->topping,"jelly") == 0)
        {
            tp = 5;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(record->topping,"kiwi") == 0)
        {
            tp = 4;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(record->topping,"mango") == 0)
        {
            tp = 5;
            break;
        }
    }
        printf("Input your size [100..500] : ");
        scanf("%d",&record->size);
        sz = record->size;
        record->harga = nm * tp * sz * 10;
        printf("\n\nDetail Purchase:\n");
        printf("Name : %s\n", record->name);
        printf("Topping : %s\n", record->topping);
        printf("Size : %d\n", record->size);
        printf("Price : %d\n", record->harga);
        while (loop = true)
        {
        printf("Are you sure [y/n] : ");
        scanf("%s", sure);
        if (strcmp(sure, "y") == 0)
        {
        fwrite(record,sizeof(struct yogurt),1,in);
        fclose(in);
        free(record);
        printf("Data succesfully added....");
        count++;
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        main();
        }
        else if (strcmp(sure, "n") == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
        }

}

void menu2(void)
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    record = (struct yogurt*)malloc(sizeof(struct yogurt));
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=count)
    {
        fread(record,sizeof(struct yogurt),i,in);
        printf("Name : %s\n", record->name);
        printf("Topping : %s\n", record->topping);
        printf("Size : %d\n", record->size);
        printf("Price : %d\n", record->harga);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(in);
    free(record);
    _getch();
    system("cls");
    main();
}
```

Comment: One observation, While== true not while=true, your assigning it that's not it suppose to do.

Comment: You need to initialize your variables (e.g., `bool loop`), use comparison (`==`) instead of assignment in your `while` loops, not call `main()` from your functions, and probably a bunch of other stuff.  Also I'm assuming you're looking at the saved file in notepad or some other text editor and seeing "Chinese".  The data is saved in binary and is typically not viewable as text.

Comment: In  fread(record,sizeof(struct yogurt),i,in);  why i?

Comment: `while (loop = true)` should be `while (loop == true)` or `while (loop)` certainly, but you never initialize `loop`, nor change its value anywhere within the loops. So It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: "I want to save the struct, it will save in Chinese language." --> How did you determined it was saved in Chinese language?  This is important.

Comment: thank you all for your reply, I have corrected my code. and yes I open the data.txt and see Chinese language, how to make it readable? @Jean-ClaudeColette i'm using I because I want to show all record, could you help me with better code?

Answer (score 1):

Make certain you open the file in binary mode.

Using *text mode* may corrupt the *binary* data of `int size, int harga` members.

If on various `*ninx` like compilers, this will not improve things as there, text mode and binary are do not have this difference.

```
// in = fopen("data.txt","a");
in = fopen("data.txt","ab");

// in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
in = fopen("data.txt", "rb");
```

---

The below code is an assignment.  Usually code here need to compare.  As `loop` is not read later, it is unclear as to OP's intent.

```
// while (loop = true)
while (loop == true)
// or even better
while (loop)
```

---

Return value of `fread(record, sizeof(struct yogurt), i, in);` should be checked before using `record` members.

`else if (strcmp(sure, "n") == 0)` lacks a prior `if()`.

`count` is not declared.

The file is not truly a text file so recommend against using a `.txt` suffix.

Other problems may exist.

Best to post true compilable code.

Comment: thank you for your answer.i have corrected my code with added "ab" and using == with loop. but what do you mean about using .txt suffix? because I want to make the file readable when I open data.txt

Comment: @Ivan Using `fwrite()` to write `struct yogurt` does not save the `int` members as readable text.  If the goal is to read those members as text (make the file readable when I open data.txt), you need a new approach to read/write `struct yogurt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it in the text file you need to serialize it (convert to the text format):

instead of         `fwrite(record,sizeof(struct yogurt),1,in);fclose(in);`

you need something like this (creating comma delimited file)

```
fprintf(in, "%s,%s,%d,%d\n",record -> name, record -> topping, record -> size, record -> targa);
fclose(in);
```

to save (and read of course) in the binary format it is safer to add the letter 'b' to the mode string. As we do not know what platform - some can treat text and binary files differently. It is not needed on any POSIX conforming systems and will be ignored - so it is not harmful. Try `"ab"` and `"rb"` mode strings instead.

Comment: Reading/writing raw structs is safe when done from the same program.  That's not the source of the issue.

Comment: It was not my full answer

Comment: @dbush and the file name: `data.txt` says somethind about OP intentions I think.

Comment: I have tried your code and add "ab" , but when I open the data.txt it was still in Chinese language. how to make it readable?